# selectMenu with list of Manufacturer from a beanmanager

Tags: hibernate

I would like to ask you aboute hiberbnate 
I have 2 page ,the first is datatable of Manufacturer "Fabricant" and the second it is another page datatable Component "composant"
when I try to add a new component to my table ,I should select his Manufacturer  "Fabricant" using the  
but this error has ben shown :(

> failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
>   com.persistance.Fabricant.composants, no session or session was closed

this is my code

```
<h:outputLabel value="Fabricant:"   />  
            <p:selectOneMenu id="fab" value="#{composantbean.fabricant}" required="true">  
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Fabricant" itemValue="" />  
                <f:selectItems value="#{fabricantbean.list}" />  
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

composanbean and fabricantbean are scope session

Answer (score 0):

It is OK now ,I change My "ManufacturerDAO ",eleminate session.getTransaction.commit() 
But don't Know if this strategi is OK

```
public List<Fabricant> findAll () { 

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Fabricant.class);
        list=crit.list();
    /*  session.getTransaction().commit(); */
        return  list;
    }
```